# Как перенаправить вывод функции в pipe?

Tags: linux, shell, pipes

Здесь pipe работает нормально:

```
dpkg -l | grep nginx

ii  nginx                                1.4.6-1ubuntu3.2                        all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server
ii  nginx-common                         1.4.6-1ubuntu3.2                        all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
ii  nginx-full                           1.4.6-1ubuntu3.2                        amd64        nginx web/proxy server (standard version)
```

А вот так вывод первого выражения пролетает мимо grep:

```
nginx -V | grep echo

nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
built by gcc 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: ...
```

(дальше идет список аргументов, в котором тоже нет слова "echo").

Как можно увидеть, 4 строки печатаются прямо в stdout и не попадают в pipe. А можно ли их всё-таки поймать и обработать? Как?

Comment: А вы уверены, что они идут именно в stdout, а не в stderr ? попробуйте `nginx -V 2>version.txt` и посмотрите что у вас в этом файле. мне кажется там будут те строки ... тогда `nginx -V 2>&1 | grep` спасет отца Русской демократии

Comment: Может они не в stdout, а в stderr пишутся? Тогда `nginx ... 2>&1 | grep ...` объединит stderr с stdout и весь вывод попадет в pipe

Comment: @Mike: да, так и оказалось. Не понимаю логику разработчиков, зачем писать в stderr результат такой команды.

Comment: @avp: да, ваше предположение верное, спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

процесс может читать информацию как минимум из одного потока, условно называемого `stdin` (поток номер 0), и выводить информацию как минимум в два потока, условно называемые `stdout` (поток номер 1) и `stderr` (поток номер 2).

оператор *shell-а* <kbd>|</kbd> ("pipe", "вертикальная черта"), употреблённый между двумя командами (которые запускают процессы), связывает `stdout` первого процесса с `stdin` второго процесса. и второй процесс может этот поток информации как-то обработать.

но та информация, которую первый процесс отправляет в `stderr`, «проходит мимо» оператора <kbd>|</kbd>, а значит, и «мимо» второго процесса.

---

с помощью оператора <kbd>2>&1</kbd>, вставленного до или после команды, можно «изменить направление» потока `stderr` (поток номер 2) процесса, созданного этой командой, так, что выводимая процессом в этот поток информация будет «попадать» в поток `stdout` (поток номер 1). поток `stderr` «как бы исчезнет», а в потоке `stdout` будет (вперемешку) присутствовать вся информация, выданная в оба этих потока. таким образом оператору <kbd>|</kbd> (а значит, и второму процессу) попадёт **и** содержимое `stdout`, **и** содержимое `stderr` первого процесса.

---

т.е., возвращаясь к вопросу, можно переписать команду так:

```
$ /usr/sbin/nginx -V 2>&1 | grep echo
```

или так:

```
$ 2>&1 /usr/sbin/nginx -V | grep echo
```

---

у реализации *shell-а* под названием *bash* (возможно, и у других реализаций) есть не описанная в стандарте *posix* сокращённая форма записи этих двух операторов. вместо <kbd>2>&1 |</kbd> можно писать <kbd>|&</kbd>:

```
$ /usr/sbin/nginx -V |& grep echo
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Особенно про `|&` было интересно узнать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я немного переформулировал один из абзацев и добавил упоминание про то, что оператор перенаправления потока можно употреблять и **до** команды.

Comment: спасибо, прочитаю сейчас.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если интересно, как это делается "совсем внутри", можете почитать [man 2 dup](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html)